# Determine Volume Level in dB

Tags: macos, core-audio

This should be a simple question. On my Macbook Pro, the built-in output device does not support the kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar property, so I have to get and set volume with kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume.

My question is, how can I convert this scalar value into the decibel value I see in utilities like Audio MIDI Setup and HALLAB? The obvious answers like kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalarToDecibels don't work since the scalar volume property isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

In general you just do; db value = 10 * log(scalar value) if your scalar value represents power, or dB value = 20 * log(scalar value) if your scalar value represents voltage.

Comment: you described Gain to DB... But in midiAudio is something else,

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. It's suited for stereo audio devices, but could easily be adjusted for multi channel devices if needed. Some devices work with the joint "zero" channel, some need setting the left/right (1/2) channel instead. The behavior also seems to depend MacOS version.

```
-(AudioDeviceID)defaultOutputDeviceID {
    AudioDeviceID   outputDeviceID = kAudioObjectUnknown;
    UInt32 propertySize = 0;
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAOPA;
    propertyAOPA.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
    propertyAOPA.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
    propertyAOPA.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice;
    propertySize = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);
    
    status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAOPA, 0, NULL, &propertySize, &outputDeviceID);
    
    if(status)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot find default output device!");
    }
    return outputDeviceID;
}

-(Float32)volumeDb {
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    AudioDeviceID outputDeviceID = [AppDelegate defaultOutputDeviceID];
    
    if (outputDeviceID == kAudioObjectUnknown) {
        return NAN;
    }
    
    Float32 volumeDB = 0;
    UInt32 propSize = sizeof(volumeDB);
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress  propertyAddress;

    //Catalina
    propertyAddress.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
    propertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeDecibels;
    propertyAddress.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput;

    status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(outputDeviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &propSize, &volumeDB);

    if (status != noErr) {
        //Mojave , use 1st channel instead=
        propertyAddress.mElement = 1;
        propSize = sizeof(volumeDB);
        status = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(outputDeviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &propSize, &volumeDB);
        if (status)
        {
            NSLog(@"No volumeDb returned for device 0x%0x", outputDeviceID);
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
    return volumeDB;
}

-(void)setVolumeDb:(Float32)volumeDb {
    AudioDeviceID outputDeviceID = [AppDelegate defaultOutputDeviceID];
    if (outputDeviceID == kAudioObjectUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"Unknown device");
    }
    UInt32 propSize = sizeof(Float32);
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress  propertyAddress;

    propertyAddress.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeDecibels;
    propertyAddress.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput;
    propertyAddress.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
    AudioObjectSetPropertyData(outputDeviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, propSize, &volumeDb);
    propertyAddress.mElement = 1;
    AudioObjectSetPropertyData(outputDeviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, propSize, &volumeDb);
    propertyAddress.mElement = 2;
    AudioObjectSetPropertyData(outputDeviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, propSize, &volumeDb);
}
```